# How to fix name spelling when flying on China Southern Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, tickets, filipino-citizens

My aunt booked our tickets through an agency and accidentally misspelled my mother's name. It only lacked one letter, though, but i know it could get crazy at the airport. The agency asked us to coordinate directly with CSA but we've yet to have them answer our call.

We'll be flying to LAX from MNL through China Southern Airlines. Has anyone tried correcting their name on the boarding pass specifically with CSA?

Comment: They will correct it if you get in touch with them which seems to be your actual problem.  Try as soon as the call center opens.

Comment: Maybe also give a call to the CSA office at LAX? http://www.lawa.org/LAXAirlines.aspx and see the LAX CSA service office contact details when you fill the form on the right here: http://global.csair.com/US/GB/INFO/KHZC/CNCT#

Comment: Btw which number are you trying?

Comment: If their US office doesn't answer (after hours or whatever), I've had luck calling their international customer service number in China: +864008695539

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas why don't you make that comment an answer, it's got all that's needed. Also feel free to use the links from my comment should they be useful in any way (not that I'd think so).

Comment: @mts OK I added an answer. I included your second link because it's very useful especially if someone else has this problem and is not based in the US/flying out of LAX.

Answer (score 4):

This is something that you'll need to address by directly contacting China Southern Airlines. I've contacted them for a similar issue before, and also to update my itinerary with special dietary meals.

#### China Southern contact information

To start, China Southern lists all of their contact numbers on their website here: http://global.csair.com/US/GB/INFO/KHZC/CNCT. However, this link may die (this is the nature of the internet), so I will summarize the most important points below.

#### Solution: Call China Southern's LAX office

Your first attempt should be to call CSA's US call center at LAX (Los Angeles). Since they're physically located on the west coast, at LAX, they do follow Pacific Time office hours. (Calling them outside of these hours will net you a pre-recorded message that says something like "our hours are from ... to ...".)

There are two phone numbers for the booking department:

- +1 (323) 653-8088
- +1 (888) 338-8988 (toll-free)

If these don't work, you can call their LAX airport office number directly. (Caveat: since this number isn't explicitly for booking they may not be able to help you and may redirect you to call one of the above numbers instead.) The LAX airport office phone number is: **+1 (310) 410-1318**

#### Alternate Solution: Call China Southern's international customer service number

If it's after hours at the LAX office, or if you're just not getting any answer from the above numbers, I've had luck calling their international customer service hotline. This phone number is based in China, so you may incur charges.

The phone number is: **+86 4008695539**. (86 is the country code for China.)

You will be directed to a recorded menu, the first question of which will allow you to select English as a language. Just navigate the menu until you get to booking inquiries and it will connect you to a representative.

#### Alternate Solution: Call China Southern's other US offices

China Southern also has offices in New York and Chicago, associated with JFK and O'Hare Airports.

As a last resort (or if you really don't want to call international, as a backup plan to calling LA before attempting the international hotline), you can try these numbers as well. You may still be directed to call the Los Angeles numbers since you are flying from that airport, but I will include the information here for the sake of completeness.

**New York offices (JFK)**

- +1 (323) 653-8088
- +1 (212) 332-8888
- Office number: +1 (212) 332-8888
- Airport number: +1 (718) 751-4682

**Chicago offices (O'Hare)**

- +1 (773) 601-8800